# Apply class if it's not there

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got multiple elements with a `common` class. How do I check each element and add if the class isn't there?

This is what I did but not sure if it's the way to do it.

```
$(".common").each(function(){
     if (!$(this).hasClass("test")) {
       //do some
     }
};
```

Comment: `$(:not(.common.test))` did you try like this?

Answer (score 1):

The much simpler way is to update your selector with **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** pseudo class selector.

```
$(".common:not(.test)").each(function(){
   //do some
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need, this will add the class to all `.common` elements if it is not there

```
$(".common").addClass("test");
```

Comment: Thanks. I know that addClass is the way to do it but checking if  the `.each()` is correct.

Comment: @Becky The `.each` is pointless in this case. jQuery automatically iterates over every element which matches the selector when using `addClass` - that was my point.